# Run macro from string c++

Tags: c++, string, macros

```
#define COLOR 5
//definition function
int which_color(int color){
//...do smt...
}

// call
which_color(COLOR); // correct
which_color("COLOR"); // error
```

I parse a XML file that contains the string COLOR. I need to pass this string to which_color function as a MACRO. You can expand macro to string. Is it possible to convert string to macro?

Comment: your function expects an `int`, not a string. what the .. are you doing?

Comment: What do you mean by "due to a parsed file"?

Comment: Ugh, sorry for premature answer, @Karoly Horvath is correct.

Comment: "because I get this value from an xml file" Any detailed reason why cant you make the parameter non-string?

Comment: guys, this is really harsh, be nice to the newb

Comment: All macros in C++ are preprocessor directives so they are processed before compilation itself.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you actually want to do is to read colours defined as strings from a text file and convert these to integer values. For this you could use a `std::map`, e.g.

```
typedef pair<string, int> colour_map_entry;
map<string, int> colour_map;

// create map of colour names to ints

colour_map.insert(colour_map_entry("RED", 1));
colour_map.insert(colour_map_entry("GREEN", 2));
colour_map.insert(colour_map_entry("BLUE", 3));

// test 

cout << "RED   -> " << colour_map["RED"] << endl;
cout << "GREEN -> " << colour_map["GREEN"] << endl;
cout << "BLUE  -> " << colour_map["BLUE"] << endl;
```

So for your example you could just write:

```
which_color(colour_map["RED"]);
```

or if you have read the colour from the file as a string, `colour`:

```
which_color(colour_map[colour]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
The compiler does not know your symbol `COLOR` since the pre processor textually replaces all occurences of `COLOR` with `5`.

One option you may have is to define a map that contains the mapping of strings to your integers.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the perversion of this code:

```
#define COLOR 5
#define intify(n) str(n)
#define str(n) atoi(#n) // Evil 2-level expansion + atoi


int which_color(int color){
    cout << color;
    return 2;
 }

int main()
{
    which_color(intify(COLOR));
    return 0;
}
```

to:

```
int which_color(int color){
    cout << color;
    return 2;
 }

int main()
{
    std::map<string, int> strToColor = { {"WHITE", 0},
                                         {"BLACK", 1}
                                       };

   std::string color = "WHITE";
   which_color(strToColor[color]);

    return 0;
}
```

Why should you complicate your code? I'd go for the second choice.

Answer (score 0):

The macro name does not exist when your program is running — you can't reference it. What you need to do is create some kind of mapping from colour strings to values.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <stderror>
using namespace std;
int GetStringValue(const char * name)
{
    if (strcmp(name, "COLOR") == 0) return 5;
    if (strcmp(name, "WEIGHT") == 0) return 6;
    throw runtime_error("Invalid string name");
}
```

or use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Don Reba said: you cannot.

`#define`s are evaluated by the preprocessor and are unknown to the compiler.

For your use case, you can use a `std::hash_map` that maps `string`s to `int`s:

```
#include <string>
#include <hash_map>
#include <iostream>

int which_color(int color);
void test_func();

void test_func()
{
    std::hash_map<std::string, int> constants;
    constants["COLOR"] = 5;
    std::cout << "Result: " << which_color(constants["COLOR"]) << std::endl;
}

int which_color(int color)
{ 
    /* ...do smt... */
    return color; // For testing
}
```